# Sublime Text 3 - PHP Build System

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Struggling with this quite a bit.

Trying to add a PHP build system this is what I have:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["php", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector"  : "source.php"
}
```

Now, building a file called `test.php` which contains: `<?php echo "Hello, World!"; ?>` yields this error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['php', 'D:\\www\\sandbox\\php\\test.php']]
[dir: D:\www\sandbox\php]
```

PHP is definitely on my `PATH` and running `php test.php` via command line works.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe put $file inside quotes. So `"'$file'"`

Comment: Nope. All it did was add double quotes around the path in the error message.

Comment: Are you running ST with the same user as your's? Make sure the PATH for that user is set up too.

Comment: @sergey - I'm not sure how it might be using different users, considering there's only one user and I'm on a Windows machine. Also, I set that when I said `PATH`, I meant Windows' Environment path. I suppose I should've been clearer with my question.

Answer (score 16):

PHP.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\php\\php.exe", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector": "source.php"
}
```

Varialble in this only path to php.exe ("C:\php\php.exe"). After save it press F7 on your php code. Hope this help somebody.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change the path to your **php.exe**.
For example i use wampserver so my php.exe is under `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16`, that way the solution is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php5.6.16\\php.exe", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector": "source.php"
}
```

That worked fine for me, good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

The modified code :

```
{ 
   "cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "*",
   "selector": "source.php"
}
```

Comment: Correction: {
 "cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "*",
 "selector": "source.php"
}

Comment: You can edit your own post - that's probably the thing to do here.

Answer (score -1):

This is the build system I'm using to run php script in terminal/Browser.

```
{
"shell_cmd": "php -l \"$file\"",
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "embedding.php",
"variants": 
[
    {
        "shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"php $file;echo;echo Press enter to exit...;read\"", 
        "name": "Run(terminal)"
    },
    {
        "shell_cmd":"firefox \"localhost/$file_base_name.php\"", 
        "name":"Run on Server"  
    }
]
```

}