# PHP console input in Sublime Text3

Tags: php, sublimetext3

While taking input and showing output from console in PHP I use the following code which is not working in Sublime Text3 but working in other like PhpStrome. Should I install any package in Sublime Txt3 or any suggestion.

Code:

```
<?php
   list($a, $b) = explode(" ", trim(fgets(STDIN)));
   echo $a, " ", $b, "\n";
?>
```

**Edit:**

Someone suggesting me this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322758/how-to-run-php-code-in-sublime-text-2) but I already tried this before. My build-system file code is given below but its not helping.

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "php$",
   "selector": "source.php"
}
```

Comment: Sublime Text is not an IDE. It is a code editor.

Comment: Can you clarify; are you looking to run that code from within the editor?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833697/899126